# pm.Simulator not accepting single parameter vector function

Tags: python, numpy, theano, bayesian, pymc3

I'm trying to do some approximate Bayesian computing, and am able to use the `pm.Simulator` class to estimate functions with 2 or more parameters (where each parameter is actually an array of multiple values). However, when I try to estimate values of a single parameter function, I get an error.

The simplest working example (loosely based on the actual code):

```
# 2 parameter pm.Simulator snippet that *works*
import pymc3 as pm 
import numpy as np 

def get_mean_sig2(mu,sigma):
    multi_var = np.random.normal(mu,sigma)
    return multi_var
# create the observed data
obs2 = get_mean_sig2(np.array([10,5,2,1]), np.array([0.5,1,2,1]))

with pm.Model() as m91:
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=1, upper=15, shape=obs2.shape[0])
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma',lower=0.25, upper=3,shape=obs2.shape[0])
    sim = pm.Simulator('sim', get_mean_sig2,params=(mu,sigma),observed=obs2)
    jj = pm.sample_smc(kernel='ABC')
```

When I remove the 'sigma' parameter, and simplify the problem to only estimating the mean with this code:

```
# 1 parameter pm.Simulator snippet that doesn't work

def get_only_mean(mu):
    multi_var = np.random.normal(mu,0.2)
    return multi_var
obs = get_only_mean(np.array([10,5,2,1]))

with pm.Model() as m90:
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower=1, upper=15, shape=obs.shape[0])
    sim = pm.Simulator('sim', get_only_mean,params=(mu),observed=obs)
    jj = pm.sample_smc(kernel='ABC')
```

I get the error message `ValueError: Length of mu ~ Uniform cannot be determined` . I have tried
variations of inputting `shape=(1,obs.shape[0])` or manually setting `shape=4` for the 'shape' parameter's input - but failed.

I'm unable to understand why this problem suddenly appears - any help would be appreciated.

My environment/system config is:

OS: Linux Mint 19.2

Python 3.8.5

numpy 1.19.5

pymc3 3.11.0
theano 1.1.0

Comment: Did you try, `params=(mu,)`? Without a comma, parentheses merely delimit an expression, rather than designate a tuple data type.

Answer (score 0):

The error disappears when the variable/s are put into a list rather than a tuple.

For the single-parameter example, using `params=[mu]` instead of `params=(mu)` solves the issue.

A list is a valid data-type for multi-parameter situations too - eg. `params=(mu, sigma)` is equivalent to `params=[mu, sigma]`.